# Google Chrome - how to disallow insecure content after granting permission for one website

Tags: google-chrome

I loaded one website via https and Chrome shown a warning that the webiste is trying to load an insecure script. As I trusted the script, I allowed the script to load. This marked the website with a red striked https.
Now, how do I revoke this permission? I can't seem to find the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome settings from the hamburger (3 dots) menu.

Scroll down or search for and select "Content Settings".

From there click "Javascript", and you should see the site you trusted in the "Allow" list. Click the hamburger menu next to that website and hit "Remove".

Answer (score 0):

You can click the box at the beginning of the address bar. It will drop down a list of items you can allow, block, or ask.